# Get value in list on Python

Tags: python, lambda, list-comprehension

See the code:

```
mult = [lambda x, i=i:x*i for i in range(4)]
for v in mult:
    print(v)
```

But my return value is:

```
<function <listcomp>.<lambda> at 0x7fd8b26b9d08>
<function <listcomp>.<lambda> at 0x7fd8b26b9d90>
<function <listcomp>.<lambda> at 0x7fd8b26b9ae8>
<function <listcomp>.<lambda> at 0x7fd8b26b9a60>
```

Can I get a real value?

My real problem is this line of code :

```
text = [lambda tw: tw['text'] for x in tweets_data]
```

and my return is for example:

```
<function <listcomp>.<lambda> at 0x7fd8b261abf8>
```

Comment: To get a real value, you need to pass each function an argument.  What that argument is depends on your purpose.

Comment: Right, but my problem is in this line of code

    text = [lambda tw: tw['text'] for x in tweets_data]

and my return is ex.:
<function <listcomp>.<lambda> at 0x7fd8b261abf8>

:/

Comment: You seem to be confusing list comprehensions with `map()`...

Comment: Do you perhaps mean `text = [tw['text'] for x in tweets_data]`?

Comment: Thanks @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams for help

Answer (score 2):

you just create 4 functions with different i

```
a = [lambda x, i=i:x*i for i in range(4)]
for func in a:
    print func(1)

0
1
2
3
```

Comment: Right, but my problem is in this line of code text = [lambda tw: tw['text'] for x in tweets_data] and my return is ex.: <function <listcomp>.<lambda> at 0x7fd8b261abf8> :/

Comment: [ tw['text'] for tw in tweets_data ]